# subquery 'in' operand should contain 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to retrieve the name and surname of customers that I have more than 1 friends by counting the occurrence of their in the friend's table. That friend table that only shows the friend_id and the cust_id and the location_id, I also have to mention that I have a location table that has all details about the locations. but unfortunately I have that operand issue mentioned at the top;
Can someone explained to me clear what I have to do, why my query is wrong. I have looked at something similar still dont get the logic behind it. Please do not refer to another answer, and if you think this question is too basic, please dont comment;

```
select* from customer 
where custid in (select custid, count(custid) as occ from friend group by 
custid having occ >=2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in error message, sub-query can have only one column in `Select` list

Use the `COUNT` aggregate in `Having` clause instead of alias name and remove the `count(custid)` from `select`

```
SELECT *
FROM   customer
WHERE  custid IN (SELECT custid
                  FROM   friend
                  GROUP  BY custid
                  HAVING Count(custid) >= 2);
```

Better to use `JOIN` instead of `IN`, though am not very sure about performance in `Mysql`

```
SELECT C.*
FROM   customer C
       JOIN (SELECT custid,
                    Count(custid) AS occ
             FROM   friend
             GROUP  BY custid
             HAVING occ >= 2) F
         ON C.custid = F.custid;
```

Comment: thanks, but that returning all the customers. and My tables is fairly small. and I see one customer matches the criteria

Comment: @Shyryu - Add sample data and expected result

Comment: My bad, there is one customer that has 3 friends with the same location And it is clearly visible on the on the friends table. I am looking for the name of that customer. However, the friends' tables just gives me the location_id/ where the location table tells me the name of the area.

Comment: @Shyryu - Probably you should ask a new question with sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The error is having multiple columns inside the inner query while using `IN` clause.

This can be better done without `IN` clause as follows.

```
SELECT cust_name, cust_surname
  FROM (SELECT   cust_name, cust_surname, COUNT (*)
            FROM customer x JOIN friend y ON (x.cust_id = y.cust_id)
        GROUP BY cust_name, cust_surname
          HAVING COUNT (*) > 1);
```